# The controller must return a response

Tags: symfony

This is my controller:

```
    /**
 * Finds and displays a Formacion entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/show", name="curso_show")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $curso = $em->getRepository('GitekUdaBundle:Curso')->find($id);

    if (!$curso) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Curso entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);             

    // Detalle Formación
    $detcurso = new Detcurso();
    $formdetcurso   = $this->createForm(new DetcursoType(), $detcurso);

    return array(
        'curso'      => $curso,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),  
        'detcurso'      => $detcurso,
        'formdetcurso' => $formdetcurso,
        );
}
```

In my development enviroment works fine (Mac) but when I go to my production enviroment (CentOS server) I´m getting

```
The controller must return a response (Array(curso => Object(Gitek\UdaBundle\Entity\Curso), delete_form => Object(Symfony\Component\Form\FormView), detcurso => Object(Gitek\UdaBundle\Entity\Detcurso), formdetcurso => Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form)) given).
```

500 Internal Server Error - LogicException

Any clue?

Comment: sound silly, but.. did u perform a php symfony cc?

Comment: @holographix this is for Symfony2.0; the syntax is different :-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Symfony2 expects a Response object to be returned from a controller action. I'm guessing you probably want something like the following:

```
return $this->render(
    "YourBundlePath:Something:template.html.twig",
    array(
        'curso'        => $curso,
        'delete_form'  => $deleteForm->createView(),  
        'detcurso'     => $detcurso,
        'formdetcurso' => $formdetcurso,
    )
);
```

The `$this->render()` method will render a supplied template name, and in the example above, pass the template your array of parameters.  It'll wrap this generated content in a Response object, which is what Symfony2 is expecting.

You can also return a new Response object directly, eg `return new Response('Hello, world')` if needed.

See [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#the-response-object) for more details.

Comment: That works, I generated the entity and crud with the console and on CentOS is not working correcly with annotations. Thanks!

Comment: I Returned that: return $this->render('GitekUdaBundle:Curso:index.html.twig', array('entities' => $entities, 'user'=>$user));

Comment: This is not really a solution, but a workaround. @Koc is onto the real problem in his answer.

Comment: @Inori Fair comment :-) I've not used the `@Template` annotation personally, just the `@Route` ones.

Answer (score 47):

Looks like anotation `@Template` doesn't work for you. Check configuration http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html , http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html

Comment: Yup, same thing happened to me. Copy/pasted something from the internet and removed the `@Template` annotation. Then I started hitting my keyboard, cause I didn't understand where the exception came from :) +1 from me aswell.

Comment: +1 I had the annotation listener of sensio framework extra bundle deactivated because of **FOSUserBundle** and forgot to reactivate it after removing the bundle.

Comment: For me it was the `type: annotation` at the bottom of the second link. It worked without it on one server, but not another

Answer (score 5):

Well I had this problem too and this post was the nearest to my problem but didn't solve it, then I want to write here my solution just in case some people had my problem too.

Seems that there is a problem with the template annotation like some people said above, you can workaround the problem using the render function but I think that is not a good solution because the @template annotation tries to do this template managing easier and is used by default in the symfony crud generator.

So, my problem was that I have FosRestBundle installed and I had to disable template annotations when I installed it by adding this lines to the config.yml:

```
#The view_annotations flag must be false to work with FOSRestBundle
sensio_framework_extra:
    view:
        annotations: false
```

You have to remove those lines to get the @template annotation working again. It's strange because I only had this problem after do the last composer update, but not before.

This is the problem of follow the bundle install documentation without understanding what are you doing at all hehe ^_^!

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 3):

update your configuration file

```
sensio_framework_extra:
   view:
      annotations: true
```

Answer (score 1):

As said by Kox and Inori in comment, returning a $this->render is not the solution but simply avoiding problem.

There are 2 possibilites :

- Template annotation is not imported. Do you have the use statement?
- Template is not known in production. CaseSensitive problem? CentOs is case sensitive where Mac OS and Windows are not. `template`and `Template` are not the same.
- Template is not imported. Did you run the `bin vendors/update` on production mode lately?

Comment: Probably not 1st, Symfony2 would throw an exception if @Template was not imported

Comment: When using classes somewhere inside you code yes. Annotation are simply ignored if not imported.

Comment: Nope, you're wrong. I rechecked it also just in case. I heavily use @Template and when I commented it out then I get the "@Tempalte not imported" exception instead of the "action must return response method, array given"

Comment: We must not be using the same servers configuration. In my case the annotation is simply ignored and I did actually did try it before locally before posting. ;) I'm on Mac OS.

Comment: I´m using Mac OS X also and the SesionFrameworkBundle is loaded correctly. In my Mac enviroment everything works correctly, when I go to the CentOS server, I got an error: action must return response..." that is solved if I used $return->render.... if I comment "@Template" I got an "@Template nor imported" error. For me the solution was to use $return->render... in the controller. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem after deployment and had to clear my cache in order to get symfony2 to pay attention to my recently added @Template annotation (switched over from $this->render()).  Make sure you are ok with clearing your production cache before you try this though.

From your symfony directory:
php app/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following to the top of your controller:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
```